# connect-mongodb with mongolab

Tags: node.js, session, express, mlab

Im using heroku mongolab add-on for my expressjs web app. How can I use `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI` env variable with [connect-mongodb](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab), the URI format for a MongoLab Single-node plan is:

```
mongodb://dbuser:dbpass@host:port/dbname
```

You can use a regular expression (and/or other String functions) to extract required variables for creating your MongoStore:

```
function createDBSettings(mongoLabURI) {
  var dbSettings = {},
      regexp = /^mongodb:\/\/(\w+):(\w+)@(\w+):(\w+)\/(\w+)$/,
      matches = regexp.match(mongoLabURI);

  dbSettings.dbname = matches[5];
  dbSettings.host = matches[3];
  dbSettings.port = matches[4];
  dbSettings.username = matches[1];
  dbSettings.password = matches[2];

  return dbSettings;
}

var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var store = new MongoStore(createDBSettings(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI));
```

You should be able to do the same for Cluster plan URIs.

---

Have a look at [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) source code. URI parsing happens on [MongoClient.connect()](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js#L149).